# Visual Studio Report Wizard - Cannot Load File or Assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting, reportviewer

I am trying to add a new report to a project in VS 2012.  When I try to add a new report using the report wizard, I get a popup that says it could not load an assembly.  The weird thing is that the assembly is not one that is referenced by the project.

Also, another developer opened the same project and was able to use the report wizard.

Does anyone know how the list of data sources in the wizard gets populated?  It seems like it should be populated from the project, but I think there is something being populated in the data sources list that is referencing this assembly that does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Plenty, but without knowing what's the assembly that can't be loaded, we can't help you.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia The assembly was an internal assembly from another project that has nothing to do with the current project.  I never solved the issue, but when I cleared out my local TFS workspace and got the latest version it worked.  I guess something was corrupted in my local files.